# Add an invoice to Quickbooks Online using php api (keith palmer)

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

am trying to add an invoice to quickbook via my app using the keith palmer php api

am able to add customers, list invoices and do bunch of stuffs from it..

but when i try to add an invoice using the basic example it doesnt get created..

heres my code snippet

```
    <?php

        $Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();
        $Header = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Header();


        $Header->setTxnDate('2013-03-20');
        $Header->setCustomerId('{QBO-2}');

        $Header->setTotalAmt(101);

        $Invoice->addHeader($Header);

        $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
        $Line->setDesc('Invoice desp comes here');
        $Line->setTaxable('false');
        $Line->setItemId('{QBO-2}');
        $Line->setAmount(101);

        $Invoice->addLine($Line);

        print_r($Invoice->asIDSXML());

        print_r('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
        print_r("<br/><br/>");
        print_r('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
        print_r("<br/><br/>");

?>
```

print_r($Invoice->asIDSXML()) shows me this

```
<Invoice>
    <Header>
        <TxnDate>2013-03-20</TxnDate>
        <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">2</CustomerId>
        <TotalAmt>101.00</TotalAmt>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Desc>test input invoice descp comes here</Desc>
        <Amount>101</Amount>
        <Taxable>false</Taxable>
        <ItemId idDomain="QBO">2</ItemId>
    </Line>
</Invoice>
```

print_r('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']') shows me this

```
Request [GET https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/rest/user/v2/666328865?oauth_consumer_key=qyprdorhgMjAeQswpCnBBuFUt5NGlv&oauth_nonce=GCRwB&oauth_signature=FKjWjA8VSwtxKvn%2ByGb1LaYd7Kw%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1363757537&oauth_token=qyprdmoCHU437qAutsaqwMzki7izqqjl7cioaZO4uTxkykse&oauth_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0

]
```

print_r('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']') shows me this

```
Response [HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2013 05:32:17 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: qboeuid=10.129.32.5.1363757537351379; path=/; expires=Thu, 20-Mar-14 05:32:17 GMT; domain=.intuit.com
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3BC45AC1AAA82F57D777FF1DAB2F9729.c1-pprdqboas30d; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 290
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><qbo:QboUser xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"><qbo:LoginName>jeffery@netconnectweb.com</qbo:LoginName><qbo:Ticket>V1-48-Q0czg6etf4a8rhn9mxnc5a</qbo:Ticket><qbo:AgentId>666328880</qbo:AgentId><qbo:CurrentCompany><qbo:CompanyId>666328865</qbo:CompanyId><qbo:BaseURI>https://sg.qbo.intuit.com/qbo37</qbo:BaseURI></qbo:CurrentCompany></qbo:QboUser>]
```

Comment: You need to post the actual XML produced by all of this. You're viewing it in a browser, and the browser is hiding the XML tags. View source and post the actual XML.

Comment: @Keith Palmer : i did this, i placed 

$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice(); at the top

and at the bottom after

$Invoice->addLine($Line);  i placed

$resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realmID, $Invoice);

is this the correct way.... am not sure how to post it....

Comment: ***View source*** in your browser and post the actual XML. Everything you posted is not the full XML. This has nothing to do with CODE, this has to do with you not copy/pasting the actual XML -  you're only copy/pasting *what the browser rendered*.

Comment: @Keith Palmer : sorry my bad for not understanding your point, i have updated the code above with minimal data and the Xml which i see when i do the view source...

Comment: Please post the *response* XML as well. print($IPP->lastRequest());  print($IPP->lastResponse());

Comment: @Keith Palmer : sorry once again all the request n response is now updated in my question....and now i see your point.... theres no xml in request part thts why i think invoice is not getting added but can u please help me on how to achieve this.....

Comment: Annnddd... post the rest of your code. Specifically, the code you're using to actually send the data to IDS. And what we're looking for is the XML request and response IMMEDIATELY AFTER trying to add the data to IDS. e.g. $Service->add(...); print($Service->lastRequest()); print($Service->lastResponse());

Comment: @Keith Palmer : bingo...thats it $Service->add(...);.....finally made it working...thankz very much for your help... i will update the answer shortly.....

Comment: @Keith Palmer : i would also like to personally thankyou for providing this wonderful php api....and appreciate the effort you put into building this api...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my problem was that i didnt add the corresponding service object for this to have effect, code snippet given below now works perfectly....

```
<?php

    $InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
    $Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();
    $Header = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Header();


    $Header->setTxnDate('2013-03-20');
    $Header->setCustomerId('{QBO-2}');
    $Header->setTotalAmt(101);

    $Invoice->addHeader($Header);

    $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
    $Line->setDesc('Invoice desp comes here');
    $Line->setTaxable('false');
    $Line->setItemId('{QBO-2}');
    $Line->setAmount(101);

    $Invoice->addLine($Line);

    print_r($Invoice->asIDSXML());

    $resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realmID, $Invoice);

    pr('New invoice is [' . $resp . ']' . "\n");

    print_r('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
    print_r("<br/><br/>");
    print_r('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
    print_r("<br/><br/>");

?>
```